# Line Integrals in Vector Fields

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

In Part A of the following, $\vec{F}$ goes from $\langle y-x,x \rangle$ to $\langle cos(t)-\sin(t),\sin(t) \rangle$ with very little explanation:

[image]

I would have thought that $\vec{r}(t)=\langle \cos(t),\sin(t)\rangle$ and $\vec{F}=\langle \sin(t)-\cos(t),cos(t)\rangle$

Why are both the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll trace C clockwise from P to Q, but the value of t will progress from one end of the domain of $\vec{r}$ to the other.

To only get values between ( and including ) P and R, the domain of $\vec{r}$ must be $\big[\ 0,\ \pi / 2\ \big]$

Note that $t$ can traverse the values of $\vec{r}$'s domain in either direction: you can start by calculating $\vec{r}(t)$ at $\pi / 2$ or $0$. But, you must pick a direction, make note of it, and then ask yourself the following question:

> If we are traversing the domain of $\vec{r}$ from $a$ to $b$, which trigonometric identities will produce $P(0,1)$ at $a$ and $Q(1,0)$ at $b$?

If $a=0$, $\vec{r}(0)=\langle 0,1\rangle = P$ only if $\vec{r}(t)=\langle \sin t,\cos t\rangle$

If $a=\pi / 2$, $\vec{r}(\pi / 2)=\langle 0,1\rangle = P$ only if $\vec{r}(t)=\langle \cos t,\sin t\rangle$

Part A of the example above uses the first definition of $\vec{r}(t)$. So, the example will be calculating the integral from $0$ to $\pi / 2$:

$\int_0^{\pi/2}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}'(t)dt$

If we were to traverse the domain of $\vec{r}$ in the opposite direction, $\vec{r}(t)$ would be $\langle \cos t,\sin t\rangle$, and the integral would be:

$\int^0_{\pi/2}\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}'(t)dt$

Comment: So, t goes from $\pi/2$ to 0?

Comment: @user1739757 From 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: If it went from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to 0, we would get counterclockwise parametrization again

Comment: Do you mind if I try to edit your answer to flesh it out a little, then?

Comment: Go for it. Sorry it's minimal, I only included the bare minimum to get the point across

Comment: That's okay; works for me. It will be good for me to try to fill in the spaces. Thanks again!

Comment: If my edits are correct, my last question would be--why must t go from the smallest value in r's domain to the largest? Is it convention? Is there something about integration that makes it mathematically necessary?

Comment: It's not convention, you could have parametrized it the other way as well.